Ошибка в Unity Engine, C#
При создания нового проекта в Unity Hub, как только он создается у меня вылезает ошибка:
Library\PackageCache\com.unity.test-framework@1.1.33\UnityEngine.TestRunner\NUnitExtensions\Runner\TestCommandBuilder.cs(94,27): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'OuterUnityTestActionCommand' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Я пробовал:

Перезагружал ПК
Переустанавливал Unity Hub
Переутсанавливал unity
Менял версии unity

но ошибка оставалась.
Там отсутствует пространство времен OuterUnityTestActionCommand.
Я искал где скачать его, искал похожие ошибки, но увы ничего не нашел.

Добро пожаловать на сайт ru.SO! как задать хороший вопрос => https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Удали содержимое папки Library, может помочь.
